# Would this observable be hot?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Wouldn't this make the observable hot?

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ObservableNumberGenerator.ObservableImplementationReliesOnOperator.Hot
{
    public class RandomNumbers : IObservable<int>, IDisposable
    {
        protected Random _random = null;
        protected int _maxNumbersToGenerate;
        protected int _startAfterMilliseconds = 1000;
        protected int _generateEveryMilliseconds = 1000;

        protected IObservable<int> _innerObservable = null;
        protected IDisposable _innerSubscription = null;
        protected bool _completed = false;
        private bool disposedValue = false;


        public RandomNumbers(int maxNumbersToGenerate,
            int startAfterMilliseconds = 1000, 
            int generateEveryMilliseconds = 1000)
        {
            _maxNumbersToGenerate = maxNumbersToGenerate;
            _startAfterMilliseconds = startAfterMilliseconds;
            _generateEveryMilliseconds = generateEveryMilliseconds;

            _random = new Random();

            _innerObservable = Observable.Timer(
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_startAfterMilliseconds),
                TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_generateEveryMilliseconds))
                .Select(v => GenerateNumber())
                .Take(_maxNumbersToGenerate);

            _innerSubscription = _innerObservable.Subscribe(OnNext, OnError, OnCompleted);
        }

        protected virtual void OnCompleted()
        {
            _completed = true;
        }

        protected virtual void OnError(Exception ex)
        {
        }

        protected virtual void OnNext(int value)
        {
        }

        protected virtual int GenerateNumber()
        {
            return _random.Next();
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
        {
            if (observer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("observer");

            if (_completed)
            {
                observer.OnCompleted();

                return Disposable.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                return _innerObservable.Subscribe(observer);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _innerSubscription.Dispose();
                }

                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Or would I *have* to `Publish` and `Connect` to make it hot?

```
public class RandomNumbers : IObservable<int>, IDisposable
{
    protected IConnectableObservable<int> _innerObservable = null;        

    public RandomNumbers(int maxNumbersToGenerate,
        int startAfterMilliseconds = 1000, 
        int generateEveryMilliseconds = 1000)
    {
        _maxNumbersToGenerate = maxNumbersToGenerate;
        _startAfterMilliseconds = startAfterMilliseconds;
        _generateEveryMilliseconds = generateEveryMilliseconds;

        _random = new Random();

        _innerObservable = Observable
            .Timer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_startAfterMilliseconds),
            TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_generateEveryMilliseconds))
            .Select(v => GenerateNumber())
            .Take(_maxNumbersToGenerate)
            .Publish();

        _innerObservable.Connect();

        _innerSubscription = _innerObservable.Subscribe(OnNext, OnError, OnCompleted);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: But I started the subscription on the `Timer` query in the ctor of my own operator, long before any subscribers would have come to me. Wouldn't that make *my* operator a hot one regardless of what I use inside it?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - No it doesn't. Your observable is cold. Just because you start a subscription in your constructor doesn't make the observable hot. It just means that you're ultimately subscribing more than once. You need to publish to make a cold observable hot.

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 - You also really shouldn't be implementing your own observable classes like this. They are exceedingly tricky to get right.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you. I know I shouldn't implement observables. This is all just practice stuff.

Comment: I don't mind the downvote at all, but could you please explain what peeved you off about the question and my own answer? I might learn something new. My intention is only to educate myself. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first code is a cold observable. Here's some easy client code to demonstrate:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new RandomNumbers(10, 0, 500);
        x.Timestamp().Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("First sub: {0} {1}", i.Timestamp.DateTime.ToString("O"), i.Value));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        x.Timestamp().Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine("Second sub: {0} {1}", i.Timestamp.DateTime.ToString("O"), i.Value));
        Console.Read();
    }
```

With the cold observable, you'll see that the "First sub" lines don't match the "Second sub" lines. With the hot implementation, they do. You'll also notice that the cold implementation, there's the same number of "First sub" and "Second sub" lines. With the hot implementation, the max of 10 is observed globally.

---

Just to clarify hot vs cold. Assuming a static/stable data stream, you get this marble diagram, showing how subscriptions differ when subscribing at times `t0` and `t1`:

```
hot source:  A---B---C---D---
sub at t0 :  A---B---C---D---
sub at t1 :      B---C---D---

cold source: A---B---C---D---
sub at t0  : A---B---C---D---
sub at t1  :     A---B---C---
```

In our case though, we have a random stream:

```
hot source:  R()-R()-R()-R()-
sub at t0 :  R1--R2--R3--R4--
sub at t1 :      R2--R3--R4--

cold source: R()-R()-R()-R()-
sub at t0  : R1--R2--R3--R4--
sub at t1  :     R5--R6--R7--
```

The results of the `Random()` calls get shared in a hot observable, whereas in the cold they do not. While the hot observable subscriptions get different values if you measure by index, they receive the same values at a given time t. In a stable source, the cold observable subscriptions match by index, but they don't match by time. In an unstable source, like our case, cold observables don't match by either index or time.

Comment: "With the cold observable, you'll see that the "First sub" lines don't match the "Second sub" lines. With the hot implementation, they do." - This isn't true. Whether the values match or not has nothing to do with being hot or cold. A hot observable subscribed to at different times will have different values and a cold observable can certainly produce different values. Only hot observables subscribed to at the same time (relative to it producing values) produce the same values and only cold observables that are produced from a static source produce the same values.

Comment: Added clarification to answer.

Answer (score -1):

As Enigmativity points out, and as Shlomo's answer also seems to suggest, just because you subscribe to the observable in the constructor won't make it "shared" and thus want make it hot.

I thought hard about why that should be and then I looked at the source code for the `Subscribe` method on the `Timer` operator and realized something I had known earlier but had forgotten because I was looking too hard.

Most operators are implemented this way: every time you call the `Subscribe` method on the `Timer` operator, you create a new instance of an internal class that starts a new sequence on the default pool scheduler.

So, somewhere down there in the `Timer` class is written:

```
namespace System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl
{
    internal class Timer : Producer<long>
    {
        protected override IDisposable Run(
                               IObserver<long> observer, 
                               IDisposable cancel, 
                               Action<IDisposable> setSink)
        {
            if (this._period.HasValue)
            {
                Timer.TimerImpl timerImpl = 
                    new Timer.TimerImpl(this, observer, cancel);

                setSink(timerImpl);
                return timerImpl.Run();
            }

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Couple this fact with the fact that in the `Subscribe` method of my custom observable, I was doing this:

```
public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
{
    if (_completed)
    {
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        return _innerObservable.Subscribe(observer);
    }
}
```

I can make this observable hot without using the `Publish` and `Connect` or `RefCount` operators if I channeled all observation through an internal observer like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace ObservableNumberGenerator.ObservableImplementationReliesOnOperator.Hot
{
    public class RandomNumbers : IObservable<int>, IDisposable
    {
        protected Random _random = null;
        protected int _maxNumbersToGenerate;
        protected int _startAfterMilliseconds = 1000;
        protected int _generateEveryMilliseconds = 1000;

        protected List<IObserver<int>> _observers = 
                            new List<IObserver<int>>();

        protected IObservable<int> _innerObservable = null;
        protected IDisposable _innerSubscription = null;
        protected bool _completed = false;
        private bool disposedValue = false;

        public RandomNumbers(int maxNumbersToGenerate,
            int startAfterMilliseconds = 1000, int generateEveryMilliseconds = 1000)
        {
            _maxNumbersToGenerate = maxNumbersToGenerate;
            _startAfterMilliseconds = startAfterMilliseconds;
            _generateEveryMilliseconds = generateEveryMilliseconds;

            _random = new Random();

            _innerObservable = Observable
                .Timer(
                  TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_startAfterMilliseconds),
                  TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_generateEveryMilliseconds))
                .Select(v => GenerateNumber())
                .Take(_maxNumbersToGenerate);

            _innerSubscription = 
                _innerObservable.Subscribe(OnNext, OnError, OnCompleted);
        }

        protected virtual void OnCompleted()
        {
            _completed = true;

            foreach (var observer in _observers)
                observer.OnCompleted();
        }

        protected virtual void OnError(Exception ex)
        {
            _completed = true;

            foreach (var observer in _observers)
                observer.OnError(ex);
        }

        protected virtual void OnNext(int value)
        {
            foreach (var observer in _observers)
                observer.OnNext(value);
        }

        protected virtual int GenerateNumber()
        {
            return _random.Next();
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<int> observer)
        {
            if (observer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("observer");

            _observers.Add(observer);

            if (_completed)
            {
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }

            return Disposable.Empty;
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _innerSubscription.Dispose();
                }

                disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note to anyone thinking of doing this:**

All my examples are just practice stuff, their purpose being to educate myself about the inner workings of Rx.

As Enigmativity rightly points out, one must not implement any observable this way in production code.

For one, none of the observers I have in my `List<IObserver<T>>` nor the `_innerObserver` are safe observers. Inside the Rx source, they convert every observer we pass into a safe observer that has `try/finally` clauses in every `OnNext`, `OnError` and `OnCompleted` implementation that safeguards against exceptions. For details have a look at the source code of the `System.Reactive.SafeObserver<TSource>` class and the `System.Reactive.AnonymousObserver<T>` class.

Comment: You're basically re-implementing `Publish`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. And also just the plain `Subject<T>` although both `Publish` and `Subject` are thread-safe while my code is not. In other words, a thread might be inside `OnNext` while another might have already disposed off all active subscriptions / disposables.

Comment: I don't have anything against the downvote but I would really love it if you could please tell me what it is that is so off in my code to bug you off? I really just want to learn. Please do not think I am revolting against the downvote. Not at all. What is so fundamentally wrong with my question and answer? It would help me to know.